# What is the difference between CryptoNote and CryptoNight?

Tags: cryptonote, aeon, cryptonight, cryptonight-lite

I saw some mining software labelled as CryptoNight miners and they have XMR (Monero) in their list. Many other CryptoNote mining software also has XMR in their list. What is the case? And while adding some tags below I saw CryptoNight-Lite. What are all of these and what are the differences between them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

CryptoNote is the name of the cryptocurrency technology that Monero (and Aeon, and various others) is based on. CryptoNight is the name of the hash function that is used in the CryptoNote Proof-of-Work algorithm. CryptoNight-Lite is a modification of CryptoNight that uses half as much memory and fewer hash rounds, used in Aeon.

Comment: So does that mean regardless of whether a mining software says it's for CryptoNote or CryptoNight, they're both same?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut yes exactly:)

Comment: For completeness, here's the Cryptonote whitepaper: https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf and here the Cryptonight specification: https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt

Answer (score 5):

Worded differently (on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5lwhuh/monero_video_the_introduction/dbz8pkv/?)):

- CryptoNight is the (hashing) algorithm.
- CryptoNote is the protocol.